# Gzip Camel request

Tags: java, apache, apache-camel

I tried many things to gzip the request(in json) using camel, we are calling rest web services using camel.

The request will be in the body  as we are sending it in POST request

I tried with adding content encoding as gzip, it does not worked

I tried to add a new data format gzip and giving  but none of these worked.

Is there any way to gzip the input request, our need is to call a web service with the request as gzipped. I couldn't get much support from google, please help

Regards
Hari

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understood your requirement fully. But if you just want to gzip your body content you can use `GZIPOutputStream` and add a Content-Encoding header with value as gzip

```
String foo = "value";
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
gzos = null;
try {
 gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(baos);
 gzos.write(foo.getBytes("UTF-8"));
} finally {
if (gzos != null) try { gzos.close(); } catch (IOException ignore) {};
}
byte[] fooGzippedBytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I tried your answer also, but getting java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.apache.cxf.message.MessageContentsList error, I searched on google on this error, but couldn't get the exact answer

Comment: @user2907217 since you are using cxf can you try `GZIPOutInterceptor` . Please refer http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/transport/common/gzip/GZIPOutInterceptor.html. Please refer to example https://github.com/gmazza/blog-samples/blob/master/compressing_soap_messages/cxf-gzip/WSClient.java for details on how to use GZIPOutInterceptor.